# Stacking notifications from GCM is not working with setGroup

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have the following notification logic inside a class that extends GcmListenerService, and gets called when one notification arrives. Then, when clicked, the app takes you to MainActivity where the notification is displayed properly.

```
public static void mostrarAvisoBarraEstado(Context context, String alerts)
{
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("alerts", alerts);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, new Random().nextInt(),
            notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Alert received")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nubeazul)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setGroup(GRUPO_ALERTAS)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    //notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    notificationManager.notify (new Random().nextInt(), notification);
}
```

So, right now, each one is displayed separately, and if they build up, the result is rather ugly with all the notification bar full of little icons.  Can you guys help for an elegant solution since I am kindda new to Android? Thanks a lot!
[image]
[image]

**NEW STUFF ADDED today!**

If I take the notify random out, leaving something like `notificationManager.notify(0, notification);`, I will get just one notification, but nothing else, then when it launches MainActivity (its onResume() method) it will only display one notification and all the "piled up ones" are just discarded when clicked on the one notification.  What I want to achieve is that while maintaining a clean display, i.e: one group notification for all GCM, if I click on the group, I will get each and every notification displayed throught the Alerts.class (something like looping through the notifications, and starting the activity Alerts for each one.

```
   @Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("alerts"))
    {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Alerts.class);
        intent.putExtra("alerts" , extras.getString("alerts"));
        startActivity(intent);
        getIntent().removeExtra("alerts");
    }
}
```

Then the Alerts class will nicely display the alert which it does, but one per notification.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots on what you're getting? Are they like just piling up?

Comment: Yeah, the icon of the app just repeats for every notification, it is like for example, for every message you get in gmail, you get a separate gmail icon and notification

Comment: I'll try out your code, and let you know what I find out. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I tried out your code and managed to see reproduce what you were encountering (I just manually created dummy notifications). So the reason that the `Notification`s were piling up was because the id you are passing in the `notificationManager.notify()` is different from one another. As to what I have observed on the `Notification` and `NotificationManager`s behavior so far, the id indicated in `notify()` it kinda represents the id location/position (not sure what to call it) of the `Notification` that is under the `NotificationManager`, not an id of the `Notification` itself.

Imagine the `NotificationManager` as an array or list. If for example, you have 3 visible notifications on the Status Bar:

> `Notification 1`, `Notification 2`, `Notification 3` and their ids are as follows: 0, 1, 2.

If you generate a **new** `Notification 4` then called `notify` passing it as a parameter, and the id 1, the notifications that will be currently shown in the `NotificationManager` would result to something like this:

> `Notification 1`, `Notification 4`, `Notification 3` and their ids are as follows: 0, 1, 2.

So the reason that you're notifications are piling up and NOT grouping together is because you end up with different ids when calling `notify()` while passing `new Random().nextInt()`.

As per the behavior that I think you are aiming for -- Joining the notifications from your app into one -- the implementation is simple when understood, but I think it's still a little bit tricky. It's like you have  to check first if there is more than 1 notification already, then if yes, you create a summary notification with the details and you show it alone (*mind the id ;)*) and all of those other stuff. I found this [blog](https://opbeat.com/blog/posts/building-stack-notifications-on-android/) though that I think might help you with it. Or you can simply just check out the official docs on [Stacking Notifications](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html).

So bottom line, simply use a single id to pass in `notify()` when it comes to your apps Notifications. Hope this helps. Cheers! :D

Comment: I added more info since I don't see the solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Saw the new stuff. The behavior you are aiming for needs further coding as I mentioned above. Try to see the blog I linked, I think they have a simple sample that you can try, then modify afterwards. Cheers! :)